# Run doctrine console using custom CLI command

Tags: php, command-line, doctrine-orm, silex

I decided to create minimal Silex 3, Doctrine2 stack so that I could make simple REST API. I am not sure how to handle doctrine console though.

I want to keep things simple so in `project root` I created folder called `bin`. I created simple file `console.php` that is supposed to run various php files.

File: `bin\console.php`

```
<?php

// When I run "php bin/console.php doctrine --version"
// The "doctrine" is name of the library that I want to use
// So that I can also do something like "php bin/console.php myLibrary --specialCommand"
$type = $argv[1];

// I want to remove the name of the library from the cli command though
unset($argv[1]);
// Update array indexes
$argv = array_values($argv);

// Choose file
if ($type == "doctrine") {
    // Run doctrine
    require_once __DIR__ . "/console/doctrine.php";
}
```

But I get following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "doctrine" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this is actually a really bad way how to do things but if anyone wants to know the answer in the future if you want to edit `$argv` you must also update `$argc`.

This code works as expected:

```
<?php

// When I run "php bin/console.php doctrine --version"
// The "doctrine" is name of the library that I want to use
// So that I can also do something like "php bin/console.php myLibrary --specialCommand"
$type = $argv[1];

// I want to remove the name of the library from the cli command though
unset($argv[1]);
// Update array indexes
$argv = array_values($argv);
$argc -= 1;

// Choose file
if ($type == "doctrine") {
    // Run doctrine
    require_once __DIR__ . "/console/doctrine.php";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's my configuration with [Silex-Skeleton](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton) and [Doctrine ORM Service Provider](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider).

> src/console.php

In this file you need to add the Doctrine CLI commands.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

$console = new Application('My Silex Application', 'n/a');
$console->getDefinition()->addOption(new InputOption('--env', '-e', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The Environment name.', 'dev'));
$console->setDispatcher($app['dispatcher']);

$console
    ->register('cache:clear')
    ->setDescription('Clears the cache')
    ->setCode(function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) use ($app) {

        $cacheDir = $app['cache.path'];
        $finder = Finder::create()->in($cacheDir)->notName('.gitignore');

        $filesystem = new Filesystem();
        $filesystem->remove($finder);

        $output->writeln(sprintf("%s <info>success</info>", 'cache:clear'));

    })
;

/*
 * Doctrine CLI
 */

$helperSet = new HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new ConnectionHelper($app['orm.em']->getConnection()),
    'em' => new EntityManagerHelper($app['orm.em'])
));

$console->setHelperSet($helperSet);
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::addCommands($console);

return $console;
```

> bin/console

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

set_time_limit(0);

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');

$app = require __DIR__.'/../src/app.php';
require __DIR__.'/../config/'.$env.'.php';
$console = require __DIR__.'/../src/console.php';
$console->run();
```

> src/app.php

```
<?php

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Provider\AssetServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\HttpFragmentServiceProvider;
use Dflydev\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider;

$app = new Application();
$app->register(new ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
$app->register(new AssetServiceProvider());
$app->register(new TwigServiceProvider());
$app->register(new HttpFragmentServiceProvider());
$app->register(new DoctrineServiceProvider());
$app->register(new DoctrineOrmServiceProvider);

$app['twig'] = $app->extend('twig', function ($twig, $app) {
    // add custom globals, filters, tags, ...

    return $twig;
});

// Doctrine DBAL
$app['db.options'] = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'dbname' => 'xxxx',
    'user' => 'xxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxx',
    'charset'       => 'utf8',
    'driverOptions' => array(1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8',),
);

// Doctrine ORM
$app["orm.em.options"] = array(
    "mappings" => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'annotation',
            "namespace" => "XYZ\Entity",
            'path' => __DIR__ .'/XYZ/Entity',
            "alias" => "AppBundle",
            'use_simple_annotation_reader' => false
        ),
    ),
);

return $app;
```

> composer.json

You need to add some dependencies:

```
"symfony/console": "~2.8|3.0.*",
"doctrine/dbal": "~2.5.4",
"dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "^2.0",
```

And finaly execute the console:

```
php bin/console
php bin/console orm:generate-entities src/
```